# Joint density of exponential and sum of exponentials / general RV

Tags: probability, statistics

I need to find the density $f_{x,z}$ where $x \sim exp(\lambda_1)$ and $z = x + y$, where $y \sim exp(\lambda_2)$. $x$ and $y$ are independent.

Finding the density of $z$ is not too hard (and has also been answered on here several times).

I am stumped by trying to find the joint density of $x$ and $z$ - they are clearly not independent. Add in complications such as that surely $f_{x, z} = 0$ if $z < x$, and I am thoroughly confused.

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent? What does $f_{X \cap Z}$ mean? Does it mean the joint density?

Comment: $f_{X,Z}(x,z)=f_X(x)f_{Z|X}(z|x)=f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)I(z\ge x\ge 0)$ for independent $X,Y$.

Comment: So it should just be: $\lambda_1 \lambda_2 e^{-(\lambda_1 - \lambda_2) - \lambda_2 z} \mathbb{1}_{z \geq x \geq 0}$ ?